# fonts attached to website is not working with apple device

Tags: html, css

i am using link ----- rel="FONTDEF" src="calibri.ttf" ---- in my website. The fonts are working on windows computer whereas it does not work in mac, ipad and iphone. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you give more information about your versions of iOS on your mobile devices and Safari on your Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the css @font-face property instead.

You can read more about this here:

http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/

To generate font-faces you could try www.fontsquirrel.com

However, I doubt you're allowed to use calibri as a font-face font. You should check the license of the font first.